# Ruby on Rails - Routes - taking a step out of the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, routes

My routes.rb file:

```
resources :forums do
   resources :discussions, 
end
```

I have my project all setup and working, the URL for a forum topic is:

```
localhost:3000/forums/ - (forum name using permalink) - /topics/1
```

I would like to replace this with a slightly easier version:

```
localhost:3000/forums/ - (forum name using permalink) - /1
```

Basically, removing the 'topics' portion from the URL and disabling '/topics' completely - so that it can't be accessed.

I have setup the show page of a forum to display a list of its topics. What's the best way to go about achieving this? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a route to your `config/routes.rb`.

In my eyes the easiest would be to define a default route for `/forums/general-chat`.

```
match 'forums/:forumname/general-chat/:id => 'controller#method'
```

To disable the old route with topics in:

```
match 'forums/:forumname/topics/:id' => redirect("forums/%{forumname}/%{id}")
```

The [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is great!

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't think I explained myself very well. That's very close to what I'm trying to achieve - but I guess it needs to be dynamic. I've added some more detail to my original post to explain.

Comment: So you want it to be able to say /forums/forumname/1 and it should do the same as /forums/forumname/topics/1?

Comment: That's exactly it, yes! Is there a way to do that easily through rails routes?

Comment: You can have several parameters in an route. So `match 'forums/:forumname/:id => 'controller#method` would work. In your action you should have `params[:forumname]` and `params[:id]`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! One other thing, would there now be a way to disable or redirect users attempting to use the old URL i.e /forums/forumname/1 ?

Comment: How do you mean? /forums/forumname/1 - thats what we fixed to work just now? And now you want to disable it again? I am confused...

Comment: Ah my bad, I meant to say users who are attempting to use the old /forums/forumname/topics/1 - could they be redirected to the new /forums/forumname/1 ? That's what I meant haha!

Comment: `match 'forums/:forumname/topics/:id' => redirect("forums/%{forumname}/%{id}")` see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection